# Arduino stops sending/receiving data over Serialport after random time

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, c, c#

I got a C# WPF application wich communcates with my arduino uno over serial port. Everything works fine for 3 to 20 seconds then i can not send or receive anything from/to the arduino.

What im trying to archieve:
 Connected a arduino uno to an optical sensor of a mouse to read from its registers, now i want to process the data on my pc.

I tried using another arduino uno and also some other mouse optical sensor, wich did not change anything.
Opening and closing the serialport after each communication did not work for me.
I have seen a few questions here on stack exchange, i looked through everyone but they could not help me. 
 `Serial.flush()` seems to be not working, or its some kind of overflow i cant figure out.

I would really appreciate it if someone could explain me what the root of this problem is.

For completeness, here is my C# code:

```
 public class SerialCommunication
    {
        public SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();

        public SerialCommunication()
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            if (ports.Count() == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No serialport is available");
                return;
            }
            serialPort.PortName = ports[1];
            serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            serialPort.NewLine = "\r\n";
            serialPort.WriteTimeout = 2000;
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = -1;

            serialPort.Open();
        }
    }

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static readonly object _lock = new object();

        private SerialCommunication serialCommunication = new SerialCommunication();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetWindow(this).KeyDown += HandelKeyDown;

            serialCommunication.serialPort.DataReceived += (sender, args) =>
            {
                string bufferstring = ((SerialPort)sender).ReadLine();
                OnMessageReceived(bufferstring);
                //serialCommunication.serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                //serialCommunication.serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                //Thread.Sleep(3);
                //byte[] buffer = new byte[15];
                //((SerialPort)sender).Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                //string bufferstring = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            };
            serialCommunication.serialPort.WriteLine("OK");
        }

        private void OnMessageReceived(string message)
        {
            if (message.Length != 15 || message.Contains('O') || message.Contains('K') || message.Contains('\n') || message.Contains('\r'))
            {
                serialCommunication.serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                serialCommunication.serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                serialCommunication.serialPort.WriteLine("OK");
                return;
            }

            //Format: "y: 0x%02X,x: 0x%02X"
            string x = message.Substring(3, 4);
            string y = message.Substring(11, 4);

            int offsetX = (Convert.ToInt32(x, 16) - 128);
            int offsetY = (Convert.ToInt32(y, 16) - 128);

            // the next three lines only visualize the received data but do not change it  
            MoveX(offsetX / 50);
            MoveY(offsetY / 50);
            ShowMessage(message);
            Thread.Sleep(2);
            serialCommunication.serialPort.WriteLine("OK");
        }
}
```

Foto of how the application and data it receives look like:
[image: On the right side is the data, at the top the current position]

Here is my arduino code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

// 5v
#define POWER 13
// Serial I/O
#define SDIO 11
// Serial clock
#define SCK 12

// Registers
#define DELTAY 0x02
#define DELTAX 0x03

#define serialInputBufferSize 16
char dataBuffer[serialInputBufferSize];
unsigned short inputBufferLength = 0;

bool sendPosition = true;

char tmp[16];

void InitMouse()
{
  digitalWrite(SCK, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(SCK, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(1);
  digitalWrite(SCK, HIGH);

  // Wait for the serial transaction timer to time out:
  delay(1000);
}

byte readRegister(byte addr)
{
  byte r = 0;

  // Set the dataline to output
  pinMode(SDIO, OUTPUT);
  for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    digitalWrite(SCK, LOW);
    digitalWrite(SDIO, addr & (1 << i));
    digitalWrite(SCK, HIGH);
  }

  // Switch the dataline from output to input
  pinMode(SDIO, INPUT);
  // The datasheet mentions to wait at least 100 µsec
  // when switching from write to read operations.
  // This is needed for the chip to prepare the data
  delayMicroseconds(110);

  // Clock trough the register and read its data
  for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    digitalWrite(SCK, LOW);
    digitalWrite(SCK, HIGH);
    r |= (digitalRead(SDIO) << i);
  }

  // Delay at the end guarantees >100 µsec before next transaction
  delayMicroseconds(110);

  return r;
}

byte y = 0;
byte x = 0;

void WaitForMovementThenSendPositionOffset()
{
  x = 0;
  y = 0;

  while (((y == 0 && x == 0) || x == NULL || y == NULL) && sendPosition)
  {
    delay(1); // kann eigentlich weg
    y = readRegister(DELTAY);
    x = readRegister(DELTAX);
  }

  if (sprintf(tmp, "y: 0x%02X,x: 0x%02X", y, x) > 0)
  {
    tmp[16] = 0;
    if (!Serial.println(tmp))
    {
      // Serial.end();
      // Serial.begin(9600);
      // Serial.begin(115200);
      Serial.flush();
    }

    sendPosition = false;
  }
}

void serialEvent()
{
  sendPosition = false;

  // Read serial data into the buffer
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    dataBuffer[inputBufferLength++] = Serial.read();
  }

  Serial.flush();

  if (strstr(dataBuffer, "OK"))
  {
    sendPosition = true;
    WaitForMovementThenSendPositionOffset();
  }
}

void setup()
{
  pinMode(SCK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SDIO, INPUT);
  pinMode(POWER, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(POWER, HIGH);

  Serial.setTimeout(1000);
  // Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  InitMouse();
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Comment: what troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: @jsotola as mentioned above: I tried using another arduino uno and also some other mouse optical sensor, wich did not change anything. Opening and closing the serialport after each communication did not work for me. I have seen a few questions here on stack exchange, i looked through everyone but they could not help me. 
I also tried around with delay() and other useless stuff for 2 days now

Comment: start with basics ... lower the baud rate ... use a simple Arduino sketch that sends repeatedly "ABC123" one character at a time with a short pause in between characters ... observe the result on the C# side of the connection

Comment: @jsotola i tried baudrate 9600 wich did not help, on the c# side i get the results i want. I will add a foto of how my wpf application looks like and the data it receives, but thank you

Comment: you need to modify the arduino sketch to the minium code that still exhibits the undesired behavior ... that is why i said to start by sending ABC123 and see if it still happens

Comment: @jsotola ok i try it with "ABC123"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the serialEvent() method. I did not rest the bufferindex where i red the received message so it allways stayed there until the arduino ran out of memory and also i did not gave the arduino enough time to receive the message so i added `delay(1)` there.

Here is my updated code:

```
void serialEvent()
{
  inputBufferLength = 0;
  sendPosition = false;
  delay(1);
  // Read serial data into the buffer
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    if (inputBufferLength < serialInputBufferSize)
    {
      dataBuffer[inputBufferLength++] = Serial.read();
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.read();
    }
  }

  Serial.flush();

  if (strstr(dataBuffer, "OK"))
  {
    sendPosition = true;
    WaitForMovementThenSendPositionOffset();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you receives data, it tries to read a full line (SerialPort.ReadLine()).
If there's not a full line available, it will block the current thread until there is or until it times out.

These calls will stack up and eventually cause the application to fail.

Comment: If i restart the c# application, it still does not work. I have to restart the arduino, then it works again. I think problem is on the arduino side, but i give it a try and use a buffer with `SerialPort.Read()` instead.